# Setting auto update trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to create a trigger that will automatically update my table named `StudentScore` when table `StudentScoreDetail` is updated. This is my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_UpdateStudentScore 
ON dbo.StudentScoreDetail for update 
as
DECLARE @courseID VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @studentID_up VARCHAR(15)
if(NOT EXISTS(SELECT inserted.CourseID FROM inserted))
BEGIN
    SET @courseID=(SELECT d.CourseID FROM deleted d)
    SET @studentID_up=(SELECT d.StudentID FROM deleted d)
END 
ELSE BEGIN
    SET @courseID=(SELECT i.CourseID FROM inserted i)
    SET @studentID_up=(SELECT i.StudentID FROM inserted i)
END
UPDATE StudentScore
SET TotalScore=(SELECT SUM(SSD.Score*(SC.[Weight]/100)) FROM StudentScoreDetail SSD JOIN ScoreComponent SC ON SSD.Component=SC.Component WHERE SSD.CourseID=@courseID AND SSD.StudentID=@studentID_up) WHERE StudentScore.CourseID=@courseID AND StudentScore.StudentID=@studentID_up
UPDATE StudentScore
SET Grade=(SELECT W.Grade FROM [Weight] W WHERE W.ScoreMin<=StudentScore.TotalScore)WHERE StudentScore.CourseID=@courseID AND StudentScore.StudentID=@studentID_up
```

But it returned an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Anyone know why?

Comment: If you search using the first sentence in your error message you will find many discussions about why the error occurs and how to fix it. You should also find many discussions about the serious flaw in your trigger logic. You make a very common mistake in assuming a single row was updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want something like the code shown below. Points to note:

1. The [`Inserted` and `Deleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) pseudo-tables can contain multiple rows and you **must** handle this.
2. For an `UPDATE` trigger you will **always** have records in your `Inserted` table if records were updated so you don't need to check. If there are no records in `Inserted` then there will also be no records in `Deleted`.
3. When writing **any** T-SQL, including triggers, you should be looking to write set-based code wherever possible - if you find yourself populating variables from one table to query another you're likely to be doing it wrong.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_UpdateStudentScore 
ON dbo.StudentScoreDetail
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    UPDATE SS SET
        TotalScore = (
            SELECT SUM(SSD.Score*(SC.[Weight]/100))
            FROM StudentScoreDetail SSD
            JOIN ScoreComponent SC ON SSD.Component = SC.Component
            WHERE SSD.CourseID = SS.CcourseID AND SSD.StudentID = SS.SstudentID
        )
        , Grade = (
            SELECT W.Grade
            FROM [Weight] W
            WHERE W.ScoreMin <= StudentScore.TotalScore
        )
    FROM StudentScore SS
    INNER JOIN Inserted I ON SS.CourseID = I.CourseID AND SS.StudentID = I.StudentID;
END;
```